# Installshield, getting the "CustomSetup" Dialog to not display icons from features

Tags: installshield

I have a "CustomSetup" screen, which is pretty generic with my installation.

When popping in the CD, after a few dialog boxes, I get to the CustomSetup screen, which gives me the ability to install or not install features of my program. This is great, however, I really only need to be able to have two choices which already exist. I don't need the others, and would not like to be able to see them or be able to select them.

I googled my little heart out to no prevail.

Anyone have experience in disabling these options?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're using InstallShield, you can go to the Features view, and on the feature you want to hide, locate the General | Display option, and select "Not Visible".  Next, locate General | Required, and change it to "Yes".

If you want to prevent the Custom Setup screen from showing up at all, the easiest way to do this is to click on the "Project Assistant" tab of your InstallShield IDE, and then click on "Installation Interview", and select "No" next to "Do you want users to be able to selectively install only certain parts of your application?"

Hope this helps,
Bryan